# Creating update in Yii2

Tags: php, web, yii, yii2

I have displayed data from another table to one table or one model. it looks like this

[image]
when I try to update that record, it would be like this
[image]

what should I do so that data from image 1 can be displayed in "Update"?

here's my relationship diagram

[image]

I display `Jurusan` from table **aitambah** to **ais3** and I display `NamaMahasiswa` from table **ai** to **ais3**. I made table **s3penghubung** so that table **aitambah** can be related to **ais3**.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like multiple model handling.. try their solution: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-multiple-models.html

It should work for your case, with few tweaks.

Answer (score 0):

You can reference Yii2 file kit for upload file
https://github.com/trntv/yii2-file-kit
That include file upload widget, manager file by flysystem